# Limit 540 mA CC driver to 300 mA?

Tags: power-supply, power

I have five 10 W, 34 - 38 V, 300 mA LED COBs I'm wanting to run these in series but to reach the voltage and watt range in the driver, I can only find a 540 mA constant current dimmable driver. I want to be able to limit this to the appropriate 300 mA requirement and then be able to use a potentiometer to dim it.

What would I need to limit this?

--Edit--

The dimming is through pwm. I was looking at a different driver that had resistance dimming.

Led: https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/ccfCYQPQ

Power supply: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DWMCLLJ/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_SxQ4Cb9S1PD1S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DWMCLLJ)

Comment: You might be able to solve this with a fixed resistor in series with the pot to limit the dimmer to 300 mA. Without datasheet links for the LEDs and dimmer it isn't possible to advise further. There's an edit link below your question ... Tip: proof read after using your speech to text input. It's not very good! Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestions. I have updated the post with links to the led and power supply. As for the speech to text, I don't have much of an excuse since I didn't use that, haha.

Comment: From the Amazon link you posted, it looks like the recommended method is to buy the [MSSL200](https://www.moonsindustries.com/p/led-driver-accessories/mssl200-000004696350002523), though it doesn't look like it's sold on Amazon.

Comment: Break it open and change the sense resistor to 5.4/3 of the original value?

Answer (score 1):

You posted a link to an Amazon ad instead of the datasheet which is available via Octopart on [AVNet](https://www.avnet.com/shop/us/products/moons/mu100m080aq-cp-3074457345633026102?CMP=EMA_Octopart_inventoryfeed_VSE?aka_re=1). We always advise, "No datasheet? No sale!" Now that we've found a datasheet your problem is to be confident that your Amazon supplier isn't selling counterfeit power supplies. The big, proper component suppliers cost a bit more but they pay people to check on tractability of parts, provision of datasheets, etc., so that we know what we are getting.

This power supply seems to have a similar front-end to the Mean Well HLG series as it can be run from 0 - 10 V or PWM but does not seem to be controllable using a potentiometer. That means that it is missing the constant current source shown in Figure 1.

[image]

*Figure 1. The likely input stage for your PSU. Source: [Dimmable mains PSU control](http://lednique.com/power-supplies/dimmable-mains-psu-control/).*

> The dimming is through PWM. I was looking at a different driver that had resistance dimming.

This driver does not facilitate resistance dimming unless you add an external power supply.

For more on the topic see my linked article.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts on this and the overview of the process. I took some mechatronics classes a while back, so I'm a little (lotta) rusty. I'll be mindful fir future questions of what to provide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by limiting the voltage to the pot. Instead of 10V for full current.